# No encuentro el archivo draw9patch

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

se me esta haciendo imposible encontrar el archivo draw9patch el en la carpeta tools del sdk. He buscado bastante info pero nada. Agradezco si me facilitan la data de como instalarlo, he buscado pero no he encontrado info detallada del problema.

Estoy trabajando con Ubuntu 19.10
[image: Versiones del SDK]

[image: Ruta del sdk, de donde debería de estar mi draw9patch ejecutable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La utilería para crear imagenes [**Draw9Patch**](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch?authuser=1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

anteriormente se encontraba dentro de la instalación del Android SDK y dentro de `/tools/draw9patch` , ahora puedes descargar la utilería desde :

https://androidstudio.io/downloads/tools/download-the-latest-version-of-draw9patch.jar.html